# How to write the retrieved DB from MS SQL server into new CSV File with headers using python 2.7.6

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to view the database retrieved from ms SQL server in CSV file using python with headers(column names)and without any braces and quotes. My code is as follows:

```
import csv
import pyodbc
outpath="path\\test1.csv"
output = open(outpath, "w")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SIPLDT0115;DATABASE=First_eg;UID=sa;PWD=wisdom')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql = "select * from First1"
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
desc = cursor.description
header = (desc[0][0], desc[1][0], desc[2][0], desc[3][0], desc[4][0])
print "%s %3s %s %3s %3s" % header
for row in rows:
    print row
    value = str(row).strip('(')
    output.write(str(value.replace(')','\n')))

output.close()    
f = open("path\\test1.csv").read()
print f
```

OUTPUT:

```
F_Name L_Name S_ID Branch Course
('jash', 'u', 123, 'C', 'B')
('jash', 'u', 123, 'C', 'B')
('jash', 'u', 123, 'C', 'B')

'jash', 'u', 123, 'C', 'B'
'jash', 'u', 123, 'C', 'B'
'jash', 'u', 123, 'C', 'B'
```

In the csv file, it was coming **without headers**.
I want to view the database as like a table in csv file **with header**. How? Is it possible? please reply yar!!

Comment: you need to write the headers to the csv, currently you are only writting the rows.

Comment: yes! Exactly!! @ Brad